# JavaScript E.Listener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a function when user clicks on an rectangle by using eventlistener. So far
I only managed to run the function by using onkeydown. The eventListener doesnt work for me.
The script tag is place in the body.

```
<script>
  var teleso = document.getElementById("teleso")
  teleso.addEventListener("click", anim);
  // document.onkeydown = anim;
  var telesoVlevo = 0;



  function anim(e) {



    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      telesoVlevo -= 2;
      teleso.style.left = telesoVlevo + "px";

      if (telesoVlevo <= 0) {
        telesoVlevo += 2;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Write a title that summarizes the problem, describe the problem (the expected and actual behavior, add any errors from the console) and post a well-formatted [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: _" "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: click == mouse, keyboard == keydown/keyup. That's why `addEventListener` doesn't work for you, you listen for the wrong event. [MDN keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#events)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question isn't very clear, I think the problem is that you are trying to look for a keycode, while if you try and add:

```
function anim(e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);
      }
```

you'll get undefiend, and that's your problem (click event does not return an e.keyCode value)

so you can actually add to the condition:

```
function anim(e) {



if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode === 'undefined') {
  telesoVlevo -= 2;
  teleso.style.left = telesoVlevo + "px";

  if (telesoVlevo <= 0) {
    telesoVlevo += 2;
  }
}
```

}

of course that's assuming the CSS positioning is properly set: a wrapper that is set to position: realative and the element you're trying to animate, with position: absolute.